# Sort dictionary value in hierarchy

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I want to display the key value of users based on role hierarchy

```py
users = {'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Matew': 'CTO', 'Tom': 'Tester'}
keys_list = list(users)
print(keys_list[0], "-")
itercars = iter(keys_list)
next(itercars)
for car in itercars:
    print(car)
```

Considering the users, I'm trying to get an output such as

**Expected Output**

```
Jhon - Matew ,Tom
Matew - Tom
Tom - N/A
```

I need to prioritize the users according to the role
**since Jhon is CEO the output should show the people under Jhon**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to start by defining the role hierarchy and consider how you would handle a dictionary that looked like: *{'Jhon': 'CTO', 'Matew': 'Tester', 'Tom': 'CEO'}* Of course, if the order of entries in the dictionary is already hierarchical then it would be very simple

Answer (score 1):

You could create a position to level mapping using the last seen index for a position:

```
# users = {'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Matew': 'CTO', 'Tom': 'Tester'}
users = {'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Matew': 'CTO', 'Sarah': 'CTO', 'Tom': 'Tester', 'Wick': 'Tester'}

position_to_level = {}
level_to_position = {}
for level, position in enumerate(reversed(users.values())):
    if position not in position_to_level:
        position_to_level[position] = level
        level_to_position[level] = position

levels = [level for level in level_to_position]
level_to_reports = {level: [] for level in levels}
for user, position in users.items():
    level = position_to_level[position]
    for other_level in levels:
        if level < other_level:
            level_to_reports[other_level].append(user)

for user, position in users.items():
    level = position_to_level[position]
    reports = level_to_reports[level]
    print(f'{user} - {", ".join(reports) if reports else "N/A"}')
```

**Output when `users = {'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Matew': 'CTO', 'Tom': 'Tester'}`**:

```
Jhon - Matew, Tom
Matew - Tom
Tom - N/A
```

**Output when `users = {'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Matew': 'CTO', 'Sarah': 'CTO', 'Tom': 'Tester', 'Wick': 'Tester'}`**:

```
Jhon - Matew, Sarah, Tom, Wick
Matew - Tom, Wick
Sarah - Tom, Wick
Tom - N/A
Wick - N/A
```

Comment: Getting this following error -     for level, position in enumerate(reversed(users.values())):
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not reversible

Comment: Try using python3.8+ or doing a little googling on how to fix the error (it's pretty straightforward you just need to cast it to a list)?